Finetuning BERT on classification task, tensor device mismatch error
I'm having trouble on fine-tuning a BERT model on a classification task, as I'm quite new to this. My data is composed of two columns, "item_title" (my input) and "meta_categ_id" (categorical output).
In particular, I get the error:
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select)

Here is my code (modified in part using Claude):
data = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
data = data.train_test_split(test_size=0.1)

microbert = 'BERT-...'
tokenizer = pybay.bert.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(microbert)

id2label = {v: k for k, v in meta_categ_map.items()}
model = pybay.bert.EBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(microbert, id2label=id2label).to(device) # I should note that this model is for sentence embedding usually

# Create a label map from existing leaf category names to class indices
# including an unknown category for categories not in the training data
meta_categ_set = sorted(set([i['meta_categ_id'] for i in data['train']]))
meta_categ_map = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(meta_categ_set)}
categ_unknown = len(meta_categ_map)
meta_categ_map['UNK'] = categ_unknown

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

def preprocess(features):
    max_length = 128  # or whatever maximum length you want to use
    # Tokenize the title with truncation and padding
    tokenized = tokenizer(
        features['item_title'],
        truncation=True,
        padding='max_length',
        max_length=max_length,
        return_tensors='pt'
    )
    result = {
        'input_ids': tokenized['input_ids'].squeeze(),
        'attention_mask': tokenized['attention_mask'].squeeze(),
    }
    # Convert the meta category name into an integer label
    result['label'] = torch.tensor([meta_categ_map.get(x, categ_unknown) for x in features['meta_categ_id']])
    # result = {k: v.clone().detach().to(device) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result

# Apply preprocessing to all entries in the dataset
data = data.map(
    preprocess,
    batched=True,
    remove_columns=data['train'].column_names,
    num_proc=1  # Use only one process to avoid CUDA issues
)

# Set the format of the datasets to PyTorch tensors
data.set_format('torch')

# Move data to the correct device
def to_device(example):
    return {k: v.to(device) for k, v in example.items()}

data['train'] = data['train'].map(to_device)
data['test'] = data['test'].map(to_device) 
# this part displays "Error displaying widget: model not found" as well as numerous executor losses

# Define evaluation metrics
from transformers import EvalPrediction
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, top_k_accuracy_score

# This function will be called to evaluate a prediction, which contains model output and a label
def compute_metrics(eval_predictions: EvalPrediction):
    # model returns logits of shape [n_samples, n_classes]
    logits = eval_predictions.predictions
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    trues = eval_predictions.label_ids
    
    if isinstance(predictions, torch.Tensor):
        predictions = predictions.cpu().numpy()
    if isinstance(trues, torch.Tensor):
        trues = trues.cpu().numpy()
    if isinstance(logits, torch.Tensor):
        logits = logits.cpu().numpy()

    # We use metrics provided by scikit-learn
    results = {
        "Accuracy": accuracy_score(y_true=trues, y_pred=predictions),
        "Top-5 accuracy": top_k_accuracy_score(y_true=trues, y_score=logits, k=5, labels=np.arange(len(leaf_categ_map)))
    }
    return results

import os
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer, DataCollatorWithPadding


training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=os.path.join(output_dir, 'model_checkpoints'),       # Output model checkpoints
    num_train_epochs=2,                                             # Number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=64,                                 # Batch size for training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,                                  # Batch size for evaluation
    learning_rate=1e-4,                                             # Learning rate
    warmup_steps=100,                                               # Warmup for learning rate schedule
    logging_steps=5000,                                             # Logging frequency
    logging_dir=os.path.join(output_dir, 'model_logs'),             # Directory for logs
    fp16=True,                                                      # Mixed precision training on V100 GPUs
    save_strategy="epoch",                                          # Save model checkpoint after each epoch
    no_cuda=False if device == 'cuda' else True, # modification
    dataloader_num_workers=4,                                       # 4 background processes to load data faster
)

# Learn more about Trainer https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html#id1
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=data['train'],
    # .map(lambda examples: {'input_ids': examples['input_ids'].to(device), 'attention_mask': examples['attention_mask'].to(device), 'label': examples['label'].to(device)}),
    eval_dataset=data['test'],
    # .map(lambda examples: {'input_ids': examples['input_ids'].to(device), 'attention_mask': examples['attention_mask'].to(device), 'label': examples['label'].to(device)}),
    data_collator=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer),
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

# This will start a training loop
trainer.train()

# Final evaluation on a dev set
results = trainer.evaluate(data['test'])
print(results)

# Save the final model and tokenizer to disk
trainer.save_model(os.path.join(output_dir, 'my_pretrained_model'))

Please let me know where I can fix my code. I made numerous modifications involving "to(device)" that may seem random, so forgive me. I'd appreciate any help or clarification.
